# Firefox SDK Extension Builder - inspecting / debugging html and dom of panels

Tags: debugging, firefox-addon, firebug, firefox-addon-sdk, chromebug

How do you debug [panel's](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html) html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems there is no really a way to do it in the panel.
So the best way is to use [a tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/tabs.html) instead of a panel. In it theres no problem to easily inspect HTML.

Some minor shifts and quirks of panel can be dealt with later, by '*try and see*' method.

Answer (score 3):

I think the DOM inspector should allow you to do this.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Inspector

Although it doesn't have a console, you can use the inbuilt Scratchpad (Shift+F4) to run some js manually. You need to enable access to chrome-scope first though. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Tools/Scratchpad#Using_Scratchpad_to_access_Firefox_internals

Answer (score 2):

If you mean, how do you inspect html elements in a Panel using Firefox dev tools or Firebug, the answer is unfortunately that you cannot do this - those tools do not support panels at this time.